# Can't open "Additional Drivers", "Software Updater", "Software&Updates" and there is a red circle with a white line

Tags: drivers, updates, software-center, update-manager

Ever since I updated my python version from 3.10 to 3.11 I noticed that I can't open **Additional Drivers**, **Software Updater**, **Software & Updates** and there is a red circle with a white line that says `A problem occurred when checking for the updates`.

I believe I've tried every solution possible that I could find similar to my problem, but still nothing. I really hope that I don't have to reinstall Ubuntu.

- OS: Ubuntu 22.04.1 LTS x86_64
- Kernel: 5.15.0-52-generic
- CPU: AMD Ryzen 5 2600X (12) @ 3.600GHz
- GPU: NVIDIA GeForce GTX 1050 Ti

A problem occurred when checking for the updates:

[image: Here is the image of the red circle]

Comment: Never change default python.

Comment: Then how do I update python ? I just keep it as is ?

Comment: You don't manually change default python. You can install other vesions when you need.

Comment: How did you replace default python? I have just test installed python 3.11 from deadsnakes ppa, and it co-exists with 3.10.

Comment: I followed instructions from here https://cloudbytes.dev/snippets/upgrade-python-to-latest-version-on-ubuntu-linux

Comment: Revert back to the default python. To run python3.11, simply use the command `python3.11`. But do not change the default python version.

Comment: When you change the *default* python, its expected that every Ubuntu tool that relies on python3 may stop working, or worse actually work & just corrupt things/data (ie. *work incorrectly due to version change*). This has more effect on desktop systems, so do not change the *default* python3 if you value your data.

Comment: First of all, thank you so much I reverted back to my default version and everything works fine. I was so worried I had to reinstall Ubuntu. Second, so whenever I want to update to newer version of python I do the same steps that I did so far without actually changing the default version with the command "sudo update-alternatives --config python3"